# How to save extension attribute in Salesrule Api magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.4, sales-rule

I need to save custom field data in `apply_on_weekday` column which is located in `salesrule` DB table. I tried too much but it doesn't save it in DB. I share my code below.

> vendor\Module\etc\extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface">
        <attribute code="apply_on_weekday" type="string[]" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_rule_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="apply_on_weekday" formElement="multiselect">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item> -->
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Mon</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Apply for specific weekdays</label>
                <dataScope>apply_on_weekday</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <multiselect>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Weekdays"/>
                    </settings>
                </multiselect>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Weekdays.php file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Weekdays implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Value which equal "Monday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const MONDAY = "Mon";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Tuesday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const TUESDAY = "Tue";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Wednesday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const WEDNESDAY = "Wed";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Thursday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const THURSDAY = "Thu";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Friday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const FRIDAY = "Fri";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Saturday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const SATURDAY = "Sat";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Sunday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const SUNDAY = "Sun";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::MONDAY, 'label' => __('Mon')],
            ['value' => self::TUESDAY, 'label' => __('Tue')],
            ['value' => self::WEDNESDAY, 'label' => __('Wed')],
            ['value' => self::THURSDAY, 'label' => __('Thu')],
            ['value' => self::FRIDAY, 'label' => __('Fri')],
            ['value' => self::SATURDAY, 'label' => __('Sat')],
            ['value' => self::SUNDAY, 'label' => __('Sun')],
        ];
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_rule_repository_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Rule\RuleRepositoryPlugin"/>   
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Rule\Rule\RuleRepositoryPlugin.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Rule;

use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleExtensionFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleExtensionInterface;

class RuleRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Rule Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var RuleExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * RuleExtensionFactory constructor
     *
     * @param RuleExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(RuleExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface $entity
    ) {
        $rule = $entity;
        /** Get Current Extension Attributes from Rule 
         * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleExtensionInterface|null
         */
        $extensionAttributes = $rule->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $applyOnWeekday = $extensionAttributes->getApplyOnWeekday();

        var_dump($applyOnWeekday);
        if($applyOnWeekday != null) {
            if(is_array($applyOnWeekday)) {
                $applyOnWeekday = implode(',', $applyOnWeekday);
            }

            $rule->setData('apply_on_weekday', $applyOnWeekday);
        }

        return $rule;
    }
}
```

Now we call API for create salesrule

`Endpoint :- rest/default/V1/salesRules`

`Method :- POST`

> payload:-

```
{
    "rule": {
        "name": "testing the string",
        "store_labels": [],
        "description": "",
        "website_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "customer_group_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "from_date": "2022-10-31",
        "uses_per_customer": 0,
        "is_active": true,
        "condition": {
            "condition_type": "Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine",
            "aggregator_type": "all",
            "operator": null,
            "value": true
        },
        "action_condition": {
            "condition_type": "Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Combine",
            "aggregator_type": "all",
            "operator": null,
            "value": true
        },
        "stop_rules_processing": true,
        "is_advanced": true,
        "sort_order": 0,
        "simple_action": "by_percent",
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "discount_step": 0,
        "apply_to_shipping": false,
        "times_used": 0,
        "is_rss": true,
        "coupon_type": "NO_COUPON",
        "use_auto_generation": false,
        "uses_per_coupon": 0,
        "simple_free_shipping": "0",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "apply_on_weekday": [
                "Fri",
                "Sat",
                "Sun"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you save from admin, is it working ?

Comment: @pawan when I tried `apply_on_weekday` field using select elemnet then it saved in DB, but I need to use MultiSelect element. So, I tried `Plugin method` but it doesn't works. then I tried `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` event observer but it also doesn't working. then when I debugging  `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` observer event then I see that data array to comma seperated string successfull saved. but https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php see this

Comment: after Magento firing `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` event when I check request data, it shows old data. magento doesn't take updated data from request. which one we modified using observer event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Data\Rule` can't set custom data, you should use the resource model to save the Rule.

To do that, replace your `RuleRepositoryPlugin`  with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Rule;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleExtensionFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleExtensionInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule as ResourceModel;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;

class RuleRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var RuleExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $ruleExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @var RuleFactory
     */
    protected $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * @var ResourceModel
     */
    private $resourceModel;

    /**
     * RuleExtensionFactory constructor
     *
     * @param RuleExtensionFactory $ruleExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        RuleExtensionFactory $ruleExtensionFactory,
        ResourceModel $resourceModel,
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory
    ) {
        $this->ruleExtensionFactory = $ruleExtensionFactory;
        $this->resourceModel = $resourceModel;
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
    }

    public function afterSave(
        RuleRepositoryInterface $subject,
        RuleInterface $rule
    ) {
        /** @var RuleExtensionInterface|null $extensionAttributes */
        $extensionAttributes = $rule->getExtensionAttributes();// get original extension attributes from entity

        if (null !== $extensionAttributes &&
            null !== $extensionAttributes->getApplyOnWeekday()
        ) {
            $applyOnWeekday = $extensionAttributes->getApplyOnWeekday();

            if (is_array($applyOnWeekday)) {
                $applyOnWeekday = implode(',', $applyOnWeekday);
            }

            /** @var RuleFactory $ruleFactory */
            $ruleFactory = $this->ruleFactory->create();
            $this->resourceModel->load($ruleFactory, $rule->getRuleId());
            $ruleFactory->setApplyOnWeekday($applyOnWeekday);
            $this->resourceModel->save($ruleFactory);
        }

        return $rule;
    }
}
```

Then re-compile code and clear the cache.

---

[multiselect custom field does not save in sales rule admin form in magento 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/361532/93504)

[How to validate a custom field in sales rule before the discount applying to cart in magento 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/361641/93504)

Comment: hi, thank you for answering. but it not works. it returns error `Error: Call to undefined method Magento\SalesRule\Model\Data\Rule::setApplyOnWeekday()` . .. means it throw error on `$rule->setApplyOnWeekday($applyOnWeekday);` line . ... then i tried with replace that line with `$rule->setData('apply_on_weekday', $applyOnWeekday);` . then it returns result, but `apply_on_weekday` data doesn't saved in DB.

Comment: hey @HarshPatel, I've fixed your issue and update the solution, please check.

Comment: yeahhh, now it works perfectly. but I have one more dout. in admin salesrule form single select dropdown perfectly save `apply_on_weekday` field. but I need to use multiselect. So, I convert array to comma seprate value for `apply_on_weekday` using `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` observer event. but it doesn't save value in `apply_on_weekday` column.

Comment: when i debugging, I found that comma seperated value saved in request. but after that event magento use old data array for store it in Db. see this controller https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php here i found that magento doesn't take updated data to store it. So what can I do?

Comment: That is out of the scope of this topic. Are you happy with a new question for that?

Comment: Creating a new question also help other who had the same issue find the solution easier.

Comment: see here I open seperate question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/361526/93504

Comment: Great, I'll take a look.