# multiselect custom field does not save in sales rule admin form in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, sales-rule

I need to save custom multiselect field value in the `apply_on_weekday` column which is located in the `salesrule` Db table. I tried a lot but it doesn't save the data in the database.

Below is my code.

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_rule_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="apply_on_weekday" formElement="multiselect">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item> -->
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Mon</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Apply for specific weekdays</label>
                <dataScope>apply_on_weekday</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <multiselect>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Weekdays"/>
                    </settings>
                </multiselect>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Weekdays.php file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Weekdays implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Value which equal "Monday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const MONDAY = "Mon";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Tuesday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const TUESDAY = "Tue";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Wednesday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const WEDNESDAY = "Wed";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Thursday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const THURSDAY = "Thu";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Friday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const FRIDAY = "Fri";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Saturday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const SATURDAY = "Sat";

    /**
     * Value which equal "Sunday" for Weekdays dropdown.
     */
    const SUNDAY = "Sun";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::MONDAY, 'label' => __('Mon')],
            ['value' => self::TUESDAY, 'label' => __('Tue')],
            ['value' => self::WEDNESDAY, 'label' => __('Wed')],
            ['value' => self::THURSDAY, 'label' => __('Thu')],
            ['value' => self::FRIDAY, 'label' => __('Fri')],
            ['value' => self::SATURDAY, 'label' => __('Sat')],
            ['value' => self::SUNDAY, 'label' => __('Sun')],
        ];
    }
}
```

when we create select formComponent field then We need to declare field in UI_component the xml file only. but here we use multiselect formComponent, now when form submits it will give `apply_on_weekday` field value in terms of array format.

now we wants to save it in a single row column. So we need to convert apply_on_weekday field value array into comma seperated string to save it in a single column.

So, I use `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` event

> Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">    
    <event name="adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save">
        <observer name="vendor_module_adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SalesrulePrepareSaveObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Observer\SalesrulePrepareSaveObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesrulePrepareSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface */
        $request = $observer->getRequest();

        $postData = $request->getPostValue();

        $apply_on_weekday = $postData['apply_on_weekday'];

        if($apply_on_weekday && is_array($apply_on_weekday)) {
            $apply_on_weekday = implode(',', $apply_on_weekday);
        }
        
        $request->setPostValue('apply_on_weekday', $apply_on_weekday);
        
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');
        $logger->info(json_encode($request->getPostValue()));
        // return $this;
    }

}
```

when i debugging, I found that comma seperated value saved in the request. but after that event magento use old data array to store it in the database. [see this controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php) here i found that magento doesn't take updated data to store it. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` event does not return value to $data in `Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save` controller, you should use `salesrule_rule_save_before` event instead.

So, to convert your multiselect field value to string before saving Salesrule, take the following steps:

1. Create `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="salesrule_rule_save_before">
        <observer name="ConvertMultiSelectData" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ConvertMultiSelectData" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2. Create `Vendor/Module/Observer/ConvertMultiSelectData.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 *  Convert multiSelect fields data before save.
 */
class ConvertMultiSelectData implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Convert multiSelect fields data before save.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule */
        $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();

        if (is_array($rule->getApplyOnWeekday())) {
            $applyOnWeekday = implode(',', $rule->getApplyOnWeekday());
            $rule->setApplyOnWeekday($applyOnWeekday);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Clear the cache. You're done.

---

[How to save extension attribute in Salesrule Api magento 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/361511/93504)

[How to validate a custom field in sales rule before the discount applying to cart in magento 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/361641/93504)

Comment: yeah, thats working perfectly. actually before opning this question, I was already tried that `salesrule_rule_save_before` model save before event. but unfortunately that custom field wasn't save in DB. then after I tried `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` event which is fired from Save Controller during admin form submits event. Thank you brother for your valuable time.

Comment: Glad to help you. Cheers.

Comment: brother I have one question, where magento validate the salesRule Date is valid or not before applying salesRule to cart. I check Magento SalesRule Module but I wasn't get any idea. Actually I need to validate date, then if date valid then i need to validate Day which one saved in `apply_on_weekday` column in salesrule Table. can you tell me this?

Comment: It is `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility::canProcessRule` located in file: vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Utility.php

Comment: you mean we can put to validate apply_on_weekday field using beforeCanProcessRule plugin method. am i right?

Comment: No, I mean it is where Magento validates the salesRule date is valid. That method leads you to `Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine::validate`, try to add afterValidate plugin and validate the date and weekday here. If you spend much time but do not get it works, let's create a new question "How to validate a custom field in sale rule", that will help other has same issue.

Comment: In the afterValidate plugin, check if $result is true, then validate weekday because the date is already valid.

Comment: hey see I opened question related to validate this custom field before applying sales rule https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/361557/93504

Comment: Let's try it yourself first, I'll come later if you spend much time but do not get it works.

Comment: hey i can't understand how can i validate weekdays before salesrule applies to cart. can you help me?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.

Comment: hey brother, I think that maybe you're forgetting to answer about how to validate weekdays before salesrule applies to the cart

Comment: hey Harsh Patel, no worries. As you know your issue needs time, but I've added your issue to my queue. I think I can give you the solution today.